# Get session variables between template files

Tags: magento-1.9, core-session

I have set the array in magento session in one of the template file using following code

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('filterarray',$filtercatarray);
```

I'm getting correct value in same template file but when i'm calling same session using following code in another template file i'm getting old session values.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
$catarray = $session->getData('filterarray');
```

When i'm refreshing the page i'm getting update session value. why i'm not getting update value in first call in another template file?

Comment: What is the serial in which these files are called ?

Comment: @Prateek what do you mean by serial?

Comment: might be issue with session name. use $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session"); without session name.

Comment: I meant whether file having setting of session data is called prior to the file which is trying to retrieve it ?

Comment: @Prateek yes session is setting prior to the file. and i'm retrieving it on product list.phtml

Comment: Then there shouldn't be any issue with this. Double check if you are certain with file execution serial. Alternatively, you could use registry if you only intend to use the value within a single request cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Clear session value below code may be help you

```
 $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
    $catarray = $session->getData('filterarray');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsData();
```